# Hard-coding a shortcode as the last menu item in primary navigation?

Tags: php, menus, genesis-theme-framework

I have Genesis framework installed with a child theme.
My client wants their themes "shopping cart" shortcode to be the last menu item, in their primary nav, no matter how many menu items there is.

*The shortcode:*

```
echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]');
```

*Current code:*

```
        $nav_output = sprintf
( '<div id="nav">%2$s%1$s%3$s</div>', $nav, genesis_structural_wrap( 'nav', '<div class="wrap">', 0 ), genesis_structural_wrap( 'nav', '</div><!-- end .wrap -->', 0 ) );

        echo apply_filters( 'genesis_do_nav', $nav_output, $nav, $args );

    }

}
```

*Current output:*

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="wrap">
<ul id="menu-main-navigation-menu" class="nav">
<li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91">
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29">
<!-- this is where the shortcode should be placed, just before closing the list -->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','my_item', 10, 2);
function my_item($items, $args) {
    $items .= '<li class="myclass">whatever</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

If you have a specific theme location for menu you can target it with :

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'mylocation' )
```

**EDIT I**

you can try

```
$items .= '<li class="myclass">' . echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '</li>';
```

but it will work only if the function is available.
About the product No. - I have no idea until I see the code that produces it .

Comment: Thank you so much! Do i place that before the echo apply_filters( 'genesis_do_nav', $nav_output, $nav, $args );
 line? Unsure where to place it..

Comment: put it in functions.php

Comment: Obmer, sorry one last question. I've added the following code and it now results in a "unexpected T_ECHO" error.     add_filter('genesis_nav_items','cart', 10, 2);    
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','cart', 10, 2);
    
    function cart($items, $args) {
        $items .= '<li id="menu-item-cart" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-cart">' . echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]'); . '</li>';
        return $items;
    }

Comment: I do not know what other functions are hooking into the menu - you seems to have some shopping cart ? and also genesis is changing the menu ? make sure you copy my code EXACTLY as it is . if the problem is with other hooks, you can try to change the priority argument ('10') to lower or higher - depending on the other hooks ...

Comment: Obmer, sorry to bother you again. See where you have <li class="myclass">whatever</li>.. I need to run: echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]'); in the <li> so it displays the cart "empty" or "# of items" text

Comment: See my **edit I**

Comment: Thanks Obmer- still having the same issue. The shortcode relies on cart66 (the plugin), so it's possible the plugin isn't loaded prior to trying to retrieve the function. What can I do to either slow it down to retrieve the cart contents once the cart66 plugin has been called OR include the cart66 plugin files so it calls a function that is available?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, w/dropdown

```
function my_contact_item($items, $args) {
  if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return $items . '<li class="myclass"><a href="http://example.com">My link title</a><ul class="sub-menu"><li><div style="width:350px;">' . do_shortcode('[My_Shortcode]') . '</div></li></ul></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','my_contact_item', 10, 4);
```

without dropdown

```
function my_contact_item($items, $args) {
  if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return $items . '<li class="myclass"><a href="http://example.com">My link title</a>' . do_shortcode('[My_Shortcode]') . '</li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','my_contact_item', 10, 4);
```